# Search a particular string in another variable

Tags: python

I have two variables `S` and `text`.
`text` is a constant variable I want to search the value which available in `text` is matching with particular fields in `S`

For Example in `text` variable I have BUSI20XXX if that value is available in :53A: or :54A: field is 'S', 
then I need to print that value.(need to put as BUSI20XXX)

but not necessary to have field :53A: or :54A: all times, if its there then need to check else no need to print anything

```
s = '''
:20:name
:21A:Address
:22B:phone
:53A:/653223
BUSI20XXXX
:54A:/653223
JURA30XXX
:57A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:59B:/REST_MA
LINE1
:59C:TEST
'''

text='''BUSI20XXXX'''

if ':53A:' in s:
    a, b = s[s.index(':53A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
    a = a.split(':')[2]
    print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
    if b.startswith(":"):
        print("value of B: ''")
    else:
        print("value of B:" + b)
else:
    print('not found')

if b in  text:
  print('match')
  else 
  print('no match')
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py", line 147, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "./prog.py", line 31
    else
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected output:

if BUSI20XXX is avilable in :53A: or in :54A: then BUSI20XXX should be store in another variable and get printed.

Comment: your `else` in the second last line is intended and misses a colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `:` in second last line of your code

```
if ':53A:' in s:
    a, b = s[s.index(':53A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
    a = a.split(':')[2]
    print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
    if b.startswith(":"):
        print("value of B: ''")
    else:
        print("value of B:" + b)
else:
    print('not found')

if b in  text:
    print('match')
else:
    print('no match')
```

Comment: also I want to check it in :54A: as well, but above logic only checks :53A:( same I mentioned eariler.  expected value can be either in :53A: or :54A:        Expected output:

if BUSI20XXX is avilable in :53A: or in :54A: then BUSI20XXX should be store in another variable and need to print